# How to use Google Cloud Compute Engine All-Core Turbo Frequency?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have running c2-standard-4 (4vCPUs, 16 GB Ram) compute engine which supports 3.1 GHz Base CPU Frequency and 3.8 GHz All-core turbo frequency. I cannot use all-core turbo frequency even if I am using 3 cores out of 4 cores. Are there something I need to change in VM settings?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You are running in a virtualized environment. You cannot change these types of items. The c2-standard-4 is a small slice of the actual hardware therefore using 3 of 4 vCPUs does not matter to turbo boost.

Answer (score 2):

AKAIK, turbo frequence is based on the [turbo boost technology of Intel CPUs](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/gaming/resources/turbo-boost.html). The core frequency is set according to the [type of computation performed](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/frequency_behavior).

So, it's not a VM setting to change, but maybe a code update to have threads dedicated to high performance computing (float and integer vector multiplication).